# Using prepared statement in Rails to insert multiple rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, prepared-statement

I am currently working on RoR with PostgreSQL.

Basically, ActiveRecord satisfies most of the requirement of data retrieval. However, in some cases, it seems that using one statement would be much more efficient.

Therefore, is it possible to use one prepared statement to do multiple insert as the followings? Or I have to append the raw sql statement myself?

```
INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind) VALUES
    ('B6717', 'Tampopo', 110, '1985-02-10', 'Comedy'),
    ('HG120', 'The Dinner Game', 140, DEFAULT, 'Comedy'), ...;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
user_string = " ('code1','title1', 'aaa', ...), ('code2','title2'...)"

User.connection.insert("INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind)VALUES"+user_string)
```

Comment: Thus, I cannot achieve it by prepared statements, right?

Comment: Not for multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

After two years of experience working on RoR,

There is a gem called [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) that can do the thing. And here is the example code.

```
books = Array.new
books << Book.new(title: "Programming Ruby", author: "Dave Thomas")
books << Book.new(title: "Agile Web Development with Rails 5", author: "Sam Ruby")
Book.import books
```